# Update a file with increment number in a thread-safe way

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a service that I'm writing in c# that accept request from multiple sources at a a given time. Each request is assigned an ID (simple int) that is incremented for every request. Currently that incremented counter variable is a global variable (which is fine), and I increment it in the following way (which for my understanding and testing is thread safe):

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref _currentId);
```

There might be times when the service is restarted, and in such case the variable resets to 0. But upon restart I will actually need the last ID that was assigned.

What I figured I should do is for each time the variable is incremented write it to a file - making sure that the file always contains the latest id.

How can I achieve such a thing in a thread-safe and reliable (that the file always contains the latest id) way ?

Also, performance is very important so I wouldn't like to spend much time on IO operations (I though maybe put the file writing action in a Thread/Task) - what do you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Could you live with unique identifiers for each request? Then use a Guid. By the way what do you if the counter wraps over after 2147483647 requests?

Comment: @AloisKraus - let's put it like this: if I get to half of 2147483647 then I'm doing really really well :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fastest that i could think up.

The disk is not as reliable as it looks. even a proper write does not persist as reliably. it could take as long time to pass a write through OS buffers and disk buffers.

In this code, i write as fast as i can, but read/increment even faster. There is always a possibility that some of the IDs are lost, from the last write to the actual state. The only 100% solution is to write and flush in lock-step, but that performance wise is worse.

This sample is a VB-DotNet Console Application.

```
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

    Dim globalLong As Long = -1
    Dim globalLongLock As New Object

    Dim fileWriterThread As New Thread(AddressOf writerLoop)
    Dim fileWriterSemaphore As New SemaphoreSlim(0)


    Sub Main()
        fileWriterThread.Start()

        For i = 0 To 100
            Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 100, Sub(n) nextID())
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("done")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Function nextID() As Long
        '
        ' load if required
        '
        If globalLong < 0 Then         '\
            SyncLock globalLongLock    ' note the double IFs
                If globalLong < 0 Then '/

                    'TODO: load from file
                    globalLong = 1

                End If
            End SyncLock
        End If


        '
        ' increment it
        '
        Dim id = Interlocked.Increment(globalLong)


        '
        ' ask writer to store it
        '
        fileWriterSemaphore.Release()

        Return id
    End Function

    Sub writerLoop()
        Dim valueLastWritten As Long = -1

        While True
            fileWriterSemaphore.Wait()

            Dim valueToWrite = globalLong

            If valueToWrite > valueLastWritten Then

                'TODO: write 'valueToWrite' to file
                Console.WriteLine("Persisting " & valueToWrite)
                IO.File.WriteAllText("d:\n.txt", valueToWrite.ToString)

                valueLastWritten = valueToWrite
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most simple way to achieve this is to use a `lock` block:

```
private static object syncObj = new object();
private static int counter = 0;

// Returns the incremented value
private static int Increment()
{
    lock (this.syncObj)
    {
        int currentCount = counter;
        currentCount++;

        // Write currentCount to a file here
        try
        {
            // TODO -> write operation
            // ...

            counter = currentCount;
            return currentCount;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Do catch the exception in case the I/O operation failed
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

The question then is: *how performance is important for you*? I/O operation (such a file write) is expensive. `lock` could be expensive too.

Comment: I was thinking about a lock, but then I thought what if I have a situation where a lower digit calls that function after a higher id? I need the ID number to be returned immediately, and then perform the writing to the file.

Comment: @developer82 The `lock` prevent you to execute this scenario; you won't be able to execute that function again until the file has been written. I don't see an easy and reliable way to return the ID immediately (i.e. before writing it to the file) and be sure it'll _always_ be written successfully. Imagine a case your application crashes after having returned the incremented ID, and before having written it to the file.

Comment: I get it. but lets say I have a 1000 requests at the same moment... then I'll actually have a pool of 1000 requests that are waiting to write the file before returning a result. which means number 1000 will have to wait for 1000 file writing before returning a result.

Comment: @developer82 Then I/O operation will be a bottleneck. That's why _how performance is important for you_ matters. Maybe you should add those requirements to the question.

Comment: taking into an account that performance is the most important thing here - what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

What about **Settings**? Go to the properties of your project and choose **Settings** option there. Then click on hyperlink to create new **Settings** class (if you currently have no settings). White the name of your Id field, set type and initial value. Then you may use it in code:

```
static readonly object Sync = new object();
public static void IncrementId()
{
    lock(Sync)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Properties.Settings.Default.Id);
        Properties.Settings.Default.Id++;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        Console.WriteLine(Properties.Settings.Default.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: can't use settings - this has to be in a file.

Comment: @developer82 Settings are saved in a xml file [OutputProjectFileName].exe.config after you call Save() method.

Comment: I know, but it still have to be my own file (part of the demands)